# check if files exists and provides a link to it php

Tags: php, html, file-exists

I want to check if a directory contains a specific file(any type, image, pdf etc.) or not. If it contains the file, I want to provide a download link for this file, otherwise print `"not exist"`. Unfortunately, my code is printing `not exist` all the time even if the file exists in the directory. Here is my code:

```
                <td>  <?php

if (file_exists('plans/'.$RID)) {
  echo"<a href='plans/$RID'>Plan</a>";
} else {
    echo "not exists";
}
?>  </td>
```

here is another code I also tried it but doesn't work:

```
<td>  <?php
    $plan= 'plans/'.$RID;
    if (file_exists($plan)) {
      echo"<a href='plans/$RID'>Plan</a>";
    } else {
        echo "not exists";
    }
    ?>  </td>
```

Comment: Pass an absolute path to `file_exists`

Comment: what do you mean by absolute path

Comment: something like `PROJECT_ROOT . "/plans/$RID"` (`/path/to/plans/1234`)

Comment: may be working directory problem. use 
if (file_exists('../plans/'.$RID))

Comment: I added absolute path but it works only if I specify the file extention (e.g. if (file_exists('../plans/'.$RID.'.jpg'))). the problem is I don't want to specify extention since file types are different. I want only the file whose name is $RID whatever its extension is

Answer (score 1):

Provide an absolute path as parameter of your function :

If your script path is parent of plans directory, parameter could be `__DIR__ . '/plans'` for example.

edit : To catch file with some extensions, you can create an array containing allowed extensions.

```
<td><?php
$extensionsAllowed = ['jpg','pdf','png']; //complete it
foreach ($extensionsAllowed as $extension){    
    if (file_exists( __DIR__ . 'plans/'.$RID.'.'.$extension)) {
      echo '<a href="plans/'.$RID.'.'.$extension.'" download>Plan</a>';
    } else {
      echo "not exists";
    }
?>  </td>
```

Comment: I added absolute path but it works only if I specify the file extention (e.g. if (file_exists(' __DIR__ . 'plans/'.$RID.'.jpg'))). the problem is I don't want to specify extention since file types are different. I want only the file whose name is $RID whatever its extension is

Comment: @user2148116 I added some information about extension

Comment: thanks! but if it is out of these extensions? the idea is whatever the extension is

Comment: It could be very dangerous to accept any extensions. What append if user ask for a blank file ? your script could return your hidden files like `.htaccess` If you want to accept any extension, you have to retrieve all file in your plan directories and compare their names without extension to the file asked by user. But it is clearly dangerous. What happened if he asks `../../../etc/.htpasswd` or `../../../config` ? Your script could return data to hack your server. It is less dangerous to provide a lot of extension available. What kind of files are you providing ?

Answer (score 0):

If plans is directory where you have your php file which is used for checking file then there is no need to put plans in file_exists alongside your filename

```
<td>  
<?php

if (file_exists($RID)) {
      echo"<a href='plans/$RID'>Plan</a>";
    } else {
        echo "not exists";
    }
?>

</td>
```

Otherwise you can do it like this,

```
<?php

$Path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/plans/'.$RID;

if (file_exists($Path)) {
      echo"<a href='plans/$RID'>Plan</a>";
    } else {
        echo "not exists";
    }
?>

</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

change from

```
<td>  
<?php

if (file_exists('plans/'.$RID)) {
  echo"<a href='plans/$RID'>Plan</a>";
} else {
    echo "not exists";
}
?>  
</td>
```

to

```
<td>  
<?php

if (!file_exists('plans/'.$RID)) {
   mkdir('plans/'.$RID, 0777, true);
   echo"<a href='plans/$RID'>Plan</a>";  
}
?>  
</td>
```